# Why does `a ^ b` return a numeric when both `a` and `b` are integers?

Tags: r, integer, exponent

Given two integers:

```
a <- 1L
b <- 1L
```

As I would expect, adding, subtracting, or multiplying them also gives an integer:

```
class(a + b)
# [1] "integer"
class(a - b)
# [1] "integer"
class(a * b)
# [1] "integer"
```

But dividing them gives a numeric:

```
class(a / b)
# [1] "numeric"
```

I think I can understand why: because other combinations of integers (e.g. `a <- 2L` and `b <- 3L`) would return a numeric, it is the more *general* thing to do to always return a numeric.

Now onto exponentiation:

```
class(a ^ b)
# [1] "numeric"
```

This one is a bit of a surprise to me. Can anyone explain why it was designed this way?

Comment: I guess it's because the result can lead to `Inf`?? `as.integer(Inf)` would result in `NA`. Ex: 2L ^ 10000L

Comment: While I like the selected answer, perhaps one could ask whether there's any advantage to having the actual code for exponentiation create yet another "corner case."  Especially if either `R` code or the `unix` `pow` function which can be called uses logs to calculate exponents in the first place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This covers the case when the exponent is negative.

Answer (score 6):

Consider `^` as a family of functions, `f(a)(b) = a^b`.  For `a=2`, the domain for which this returns integer is limited to the values [0,62] (assuming 64-bit signed integers).  That is a very small subset of the valid inputs.  The domain only gets smaller as `a` increases.

Comment: interesting.  I think I like Rob Lyndon's answer better ("the integers are not closed [mathematically] under the `^` operation"), but yours is reasonable ("the integers are not closed [computationally] under the `^` operation") -- but this gets tricky because one has to start deciding on mushy/pragmatic grounds ...

Answer (score 0):

Its simple adding, subtracting, and multiplying two integers results in integer. while dividing or performing exponentiation results in number with/without decimal that why shown numeric instead of integer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible `a^b` was implemented as something like `exp(b * log(a))`?

Comment: Without proof, this kind of remark is best left as a comment imo.

Comment: Oddly enough :-) that was my comment a while ago.  I should be more proactive and go peek at the base source code.