# Why is the default return type of `ceiling` and `floor` numeric?

Tags: r, arithmetic-expressions

Why are the following all `"numeric"`?

```
class(ceiling(3))
class(ceiling(3L))
class(ceiling(3.1))
class(floor(2))
class(floor(2L))
class(floor(2.1))
```

This seems like one arithmetic operation where the result is unambiguously an integer (unlike, say, [exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887763/why-does-a-b-return-a-numeric-when-both-a-and-b-are-integers)), regardless of inputs (it's an error to pass a complex number).

I tried poking around for an answer related in the underlying `C` code but didn't really get anywhere.

I also learned that, while `"%/%"(x,y)` should also always be an integer, the `class` of the results depends on the input types, e.g. `5%/%2`, `6%/%2` and `6%/%2L` are all `numeric`, but `5L%/%2L` and `6L%/%2L` are both `integer` (something about this is mentioned in `?Arithmetic`); this doesn't really make sense to me either, but at least it's documented.

Is there a simple reason for returning `numeric` objects from `ceiling` and `floor`? If it were about inefficiency due to re-casting (which seems may be the case for integer division), I would expect `class(ceiling(3L))` to be `"integer"`, so what's going on?

Comment: not sure if this is a satisfactory solution, but see `?mode` "Modes have the same set of names as types (see typeof) except that types "integer" and "double" are returned as "numeric"..."

Comment: completely random guess - maybe someone wanted to be able to do `ceiling(Inf)` and not get `NA` as a result?

Comment: @eddi thanks, didn't realize `as.integer(Inf)` was `NA`, so you might be on to something...

Comment: Because the corresponding C/C++ functions return a double as well. And why so? Probably to involve only the floating point unit of the processor and avoid an operation, i.e. the integer cast, that is not always necessary (and if you need it, is really simple to add...)

Comment: @digEmAll I thought about that, but there shouldn't be a cast necessary for `ceiling(3L)`. Perhaps you'd care to elaborate on how `C`/`C++` versions `ceil` work when given an integer.

Comment: In case of integer input, well, why would you call ceil/floor on an integer value ? For sure R and C/C++ developers didn't care to implement a useless overload taking an integer and returning itself...

Comment: @digEmAll it's pretty easy to imagine cases you'd do just that, e.g. `x<-list(1,1L); lapply(x,ceiling)`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: yes, but in those cases I suspect there's always some kind of "problem" in the code... I mean, why would you call ceiling on a list where you know that there will be some integers and some doubles, and even more bad, why do you have a list of numbers of different types ? How did you get there ? It's easy to get unexpected types in R (it's poorly typed afterall), but it doesn't mean that is a good thing, and usually it's a *code smell* IMO...

Comment: @digEmAll that's just post-hoc justifications - who cares why or how he got there. Point is there is nothing intrinsically wrong with wanting to do what he suggests, and there is no intrinsic reason why `ceiling` on an integer should return a float.

Comment: @eddi: of course there's nothing wrong, but if you start to add an overload to ceiling/floor just to take an integer and return itself (if it's not useless this...), you'll finish to create all kind of useless functions only because one does not care about how he got a list of integers and floats together... well, if you don't care about that, why do you care that ceiling that list returns all numeric instead of integer and numeric?

Comment: @digEmAll I honestly don't understand your point - the purpose of any function is to process input and produce output, it's emphatically not to quiz the user's intentions if there is nothing intrinsically wrong with them (like if you passed it a character string). This function doesn't do that too well for integers, especially since in the help it claims to be a generic.

Comment: @digEmAll check out the link posted by joran in eddi's answer below. Seems like there is a perfectly reasonable place to need the flexibility I'm getting at.

Comment: @eddi: I basically agree with your statement, but, in addition to my point about utility of these functions, I think also there's a technical reason behind the decision to not implement these variants. AFAIK S3 generic functions do not apply to `atomic` types (integer, numeric, logical etc); so you can't use generic dispatching system, but you need some sort of if-statement inside the default implementation to chek whether is integer or double. This adds a conditional jump (=performance loss) inside a function that has to be as fast as possible (imagine if you use it millions of times...)

Comment: @eddi: so, R-developers probably thought that if you really need it, you can just create a wrapper e.g. `ceilingIntAware <- function(x) if(is.integer(x))x else ceiling(x)`

Comment: @digEmAll given everything else that's going on in the C code for that function, I really don't think an extra "if" will matter much, and you can force the compiler to pick the numeric branch by default, so that there is no jump and according cache performance loss (and in the case that there *is* a jump, you do at least get a cycle back, since you won't have to do anything). That said, I personally don't care about this issue and have no stake in it.

Comment: @eddi: I mostly agree with you, probably the introduction of a jump woudn't cause performance loss, anyway I'm still on the idea that this modification is basically useless (or is useful in the 0.01% of the cases) so developers have no interest in implementing it. That said, I also don't care so much about this so I won't go on further discussions and sorry for being so pedantic ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't *know* if this is why `ceiling` was designed to return `numeric`, but the following example shows the limitations `ceiling` would have if it actually returned an integer:

```
options(digits = 15)
.Machine$integer.max + 1.4
#[1] 2147483648.4

ceiling(.Machine$integer.max + 1.4)
#[1] 2147483649

as.integer(ceiling(.Machine$integer.max + 1.4))
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

That said, there is no good reason that I see why `ceiling` doesn't return an integer when given an integer input.

Comment: Somewhat tangentially related is [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/shouldn-t-seq-my-int-vector-length-out-y-be-an-integer-vector-td4709180.html).

Comment: @MichaelChirico: About joran's link, yes `seq` seems a little bit messy about the returned types... for instance `seq(1L,length.out=6L)` returns numeric while `seq(1L,by=1L,length.out=6L)` returns integer... that being said, probably this particular problem can be solved by adding an overload of `ceiling` (and for sure also in other ways...), but my point is ceiling/floor on integers are mostly useless (in the sense that you can obtain the same by not doing anything) and I don't think R-developers are interested in adding unnecessary functions...

Comment: About the reason of `ceiling(double)` returning a double, I agree with eddi that integer size limitation might be the cause...

Comment: This is great, but doesn't close the issue for me--seems this problem would plague any integer-valued function, and I don't see much reason to care about using `ceiling`/`floor` on massive numbers--seems more like a concern for `round(x,-n)` (how often do people care about the 1s digtit of a 10-digit number, anyway?)

Comment: @MichaelChirico that's the exact same fallacy as what digEmAll was saying above. You don't design functions by just thinking of uses that *you* yourself can think of. You design functions to do the most they possibly can within whatever external constraints you have.

Comment: I would consider "memory usage" an external constraint, so the decision to return `numeric` instead of `integer` runs up against that--so indeed the designers need to take this into account. Anyway, I'm surprised that there is no authoritative source on this topic--it _does_ seem like a design choice _was_ made, after all :\

Comment: meh, that's just grasping at straws - I think losing information is a much more important concern; btw I just ran a google search for this question - and apparently it has come up in basically every single language you can think of, and the answer is the same everywhere (the above)

Comment: interesting, as the first thing I found about another language was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378282/ceiling-and-floor-function-in-fortran-arent-they-supposed-to-return-integers) which I read as being the opposite... anyway thanks to you and @digEmAll for your time, I know it's not overly important--I really expected there to be a simple answer & an authoritative source.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm pretty sure integers and real's have same size in fortran - if that's the case, then it would make perfect sense to return integers

Comment: @MichaelChirico, regarding the Fortran behaviour: Fortran also offers the `ieee_rint` function for rounding to nearest integer (according to rounding mode) in the IEEE datatype, rather than converting the result to integer.

Comment: Looking back, I think this must be the answer. `double` in, `integer` out is bound to lead to errors unexpectedly. Better to force the user to declare they'd like an integer explicitly, I reckon. Even on 100,000,000 elements, `as.integer(floor(x))` only takes 0.3 seconds more than `floor(x)`, so the efficiency cost of this is minimal.